# How do I force execjs to use Node.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, execjs

I have a rails app, and I want to force execjs to user Node.js as the javascript runtime. How do I even check which runtime execjs is using?

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I figured out how to set the javascript runtime. In config/boot.rb I put the following line: `ENV['EXECJS_RUNTIME'] = 'Node'`

Comment: Better option is to set shell env variable `EXECJS_RUNTIME`.

Comment: Hey @ŁukaszNiemier, What's the value that has to be assigned to EXECJS_RUNTIME? I used **"export EXECJS_RUNTIME=/opt/node-v4.4.5-linux-x64/bin"**. But now its showing the error `wrong constant name /opt/node-v4.4.5-linux-x64/bin`.

Comment: OK I did that now the error is **Gem Load Error is: Node.js (V8) runtime is not available on this system**. I don't want to install NodeJS from any package manager. So I downloaded NodeJS from [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.4.5/node-v4.4.5-linux-x64.tar.xz). How can I tell rails to find node.js in the directory **/opt/node-v4.4.5-linux-x64/bin**?

Comment: Is `/opt/node-v4.4.5-linux-x64/bin` on your path? If it is not, add it, otherwise open a new question to address this problem.

Answer (score 21):

While [Max 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14884754/4061602) is perfectly valid and good if you want to globally set this option, it's worth noting that there's a simpler way to do it. To print out the current runtime, after importing ExecJS via `require 'execjs'`, just run

```
puts ExecJS.runtime.name
```

And to set the current runtime, just use

```
ExecJS.runtime = ExecJS::Runtimes::Node
```

Answer (score 4):

If you still have `public/index.html` then it will show you what JS engine is used. If you don't have one then here you go https://gist.github.com/2029491.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did not know you could do that. I also figured out how to set the javascript runtime. In config/boot.rb I put the following line: `ENV['EXECJS_RUNTIME'] = 'Node'`.

Comment: @Max wish you'd put that in as an answer!